# How can you make your android application occupy only half of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, screen-size

I have a list, but it will occupy all the screen of the tablet. Is there a way to make it only occupy half , or 1/4 of the tablet screen?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following in your XML for **vertical** split of screen:
Here we are using weightsum and weight attributes. 
You can adjust the weight property to get the desired results in terms of half or quarter etc.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

  <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="50"
     android:background="@android:color/black" >

     <!-- Your RelativeLayout Items -->

  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In order to get the same in **horizontal manner**, the below would be useful:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="100" >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

      <!-- Your RelativeLayout Items -->

  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**EDIT:**
To display as widgets, You can refer tutorials here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html and here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_widgets.htm

Comment: please see what I said about the other answer.

Comment: @user3516943:For that, you must only create your app as a widget. Similar to weather widgets etc. normally available in phone. You can refer edit

Comment: Okay So the answer is Widgets as a display. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

Add another blank view or the view that you want to place in another half. Set its layout weight to 0.5: `android:layout_weight=".5"`.

Set `android:layout_weight=".5"` for `ListView`.

Note that setting layout_weight to .5, if there is a single view in a container would have no effect.

Good Luck!

Comment: What i mean is that your application only occupies the half of the screen. So, you can see the other application icons. So if there is an application that can occupy only half of the screen, you can run both.